# Interested in unit testing with a static framework, similar to FuelPHP, but not sure where to start

Tags: php, unit-testing, static

As the title says, I'm trying to understand how to unit test (or maybe some other sort of test) a framework that is built similar to FuelPHP where you utilize static calls to set and access everything.

This leads to code like:

```
class Appointment {
  public static function updateStartTime($binds) {
     $query = "UPDATE appointment SET start_time = :start_time 
       WHERE appointment_id = :appointment_id";
     return DB::update($query, $binds);
  }
}
```

And you end up with controller code that looks like:

```
$result = Appointment::updateStartTime(array(
  'start_time' => '10:00 am', 
  'appointment_id' => 10
));
```

So to test the Appointment::updateStartTime method, I need to be able to provide a fake DB::update method to it, but I'm not sure where to start on that.

I know that I could just include a mock class as part of the test suite:

```
class DB {
  public static function update($params) { return 'success'; }
}
```

But this seems tedious.  Is there a better way to add test coverage to my framework, while still using this coding style?

Comment: Most of FuelPHP already has unit tests included. Two things worth remembering:

FuelPHP does not use static methods for everything, they are available as well as an instantiated approach. Test either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Static Methods are Death to Testability](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/). PHPUnit offers some mocks for static class functions but this works only under certain conditions (only possible within classes themselves, classes must use late static binding, see [Stubbing and Mocking Static Methods](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html)).

So generally I would say: Don't test the framework, this should be done within the framework community. Instead just don't use static classes in your own code, so you can unit-test your own code.

Comment: +1 - static methods are good when used over the top of instantiated classes - you can use them to provide access to a single instance, but your tests would operate against the classes below the static interface and you would inject the dependencies: http://www.enhance-php.com/Content/Mocks-And-Stubs/